# Running perl script by making it executable

Tags: perl, shell

I am learning perl and trying to execute this script  :

```
 #!/bin/perl

$name ="Manish";
print $name;
```

I saved this program with test.pl name and change its mode to make it executable :

```
chmod u+x test.pl
```

When i did **which perl** i got **/bin/perl** where perl has been installed .

Problem :- When i am running script like

```
perl test.pl
```

its fine ..

but when i am running it as ./test.pl its showing

```
./test.pl[6]: =Manish:  not found
```

may be its interpreting that as a shell script.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Make sure `#!` are the first two symbols in the first line of your code. The way you've added the code into your question, it looks like there's a whitespace symbol preceding those.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the space character in front of the `#!` line.

```
#!/bin/perl
```

Not:

```
 #!/bin/perl
```